# how to add drives in tree view control in vb 6.0 (like window explorer)

Tags: vb6

can any one help me to add all the drives of my computer in tree view..

```
       Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

       Private Sub Form_Load()
         Dim path As String
         path = "D:\MP3"
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add , , path, path
            Call addtotree(path, TreeView1)
       End Sub
       Private Sub addtotree(path As String, tv As TreeView)
       Dim folder1 As Folder
            For Each folder1 In fs.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
                   tv.Nodes.Add path, tvwChild, path & "\" & folder1.Name, folder1.Name
                   Call addtotree(path & "\" & folder1.Name, tv)
            Next
       End Sub
```

i am doing like this to add nodes and sub nodes but i don't know how to add dynamically all the drives and folder like window explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure from your code sample what you're trying to do. If you want to add the drives to your treeview iterate the `FileSystemObject.Drives` collection. If you are trying to populate the folders under the drives, get the drives, and as the user expands them find the folders under them. Here is a sample that gets drives.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const EXPANDING = " (expanding...)"

Private Sub LoadDrives(ByVal TreeviewCtrl As TreeView)
    Dim objFso As FileSystemObject
    Dim objDrive As Drive
    Dim objNode As MSComctlLib.Node

    On Error GoTo errLoadDrives

    Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass

    TreeviewCtrl.Nodes.Clear
    Set objFso = New FileSystemObject
    For Each objDrive In objFso.Drives
        Set objNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, tvwFirst, objDrive.Path, objDrive.Path & "\" & IIf(Len(objDrive.ShareName) > 0, " (" & Replace$(objDrive.ShareName, "\\", "") & ")", ""))
        If objDrive.IsReady Then
            If objDrive.RootFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
                TreeviewCtrl.Nodes.Add objNode, tvwChild
            End If
        End If
    Next objDrive
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault

    Exit Sub

errLoadDrives:
    Set objFso = Nothing
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_Expand(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

    On Error GoTo errTreeView1_Expand

    Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    Node.Text = Node.Text & EXPANDING ' user feedback for longer operations
    TreeView1.Refresh
    Call AddToTree(Node)
    Node.Text = Replace$(Node.Text, EXPANDING, "")
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault

    Exit Sub

errTreeView1_Expand:
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault
    MsgBox "There was an error getting the child folders." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, Err.Source


End Sub

Private Sub AddToTree(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim objParentNode As MSComctlLib.Node
    Dim objFso As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim objNode As MSComctlLib.Node

    On Error GoTo errAddToTree

    ' remove any place holder node
    If Node.Child.Key = "" Then
        TreeView1.Nodes.Remove Node.Child.Index
    End If

    strPath = Node.Key & "\"  ' get the path of the current node

    Set objFso = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Set objNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Node, tvwChild, objSubFolder.Path, objSubFolder.Name)
        If objSubFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Or objSubFolder.Files.Count > 0 Then ' add an empty place holder node
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add objNode, tvwChild
        End If
    Next objSubFolder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add Node, tvwChild, Node.Key & "\" & objFile.Name, objFile.Name, "leaf"
    Next objFile

    Node.EnsureVisible

    Exit Sub

errAddToTree:
    If Err.Number = 70 Then 'permission denied - ignore it and move on
        Resume Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You do it just like you are doing it now. Use the FileSystemObject to iterate the folders under the drive and add them to the drive node.

Comment: @user3085836 I edited my answer to explicitly show you how to modify and use your existing code to add sub folders.

Comment: hi jac your code is not expanding any folder or file. it just showing drive letter in treeview only..

Comment: @user3085836 Needed to add code to create place holder child nodes under the drives.

Comment: @user3085836 Just add an empty child node. It's only purpose is to create the checkbox / allow the parent node to expand. When you populate the child nodes for real the first thing you do is to remove the empty node.